# Images in Magento widgets

Tags: magento, widget, magento-1.4

I am developing a site for a fashion client in Magento Community version 1.4.2 and as part of this project I need to have some customized home page promotion blocks to feature specific products or categories of products. For this I thought I would write my own widget and have made pretty good progress in this with the exception of how to deal with images. I need to include an image as part of the promotion. In my widget definition file I included the following parameter

```
        <image>
            <label>Image</label>
            <description>Promotion image</description>
            <visible>1</visible>
            <type>image</type>
        </image>
```

This seemed at first to work fine and when creating/editing a widget in the admin back end a file upload field is included in the widget options however on saving the form the image does not appear to be uploaded, or its details retained in the database. Does anyone else have experience of using images in widgets and what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, I have mostly the same isuue .
How do you finally solve it ?
ANy help ?

Answer (score 26):

There are a couple reason why it doesn't save/upload the image:

- The form `enctype` needs to be "`multipart/form-data`" for a file upload to work
- Even if you change the form `enctype` to "`multipart/form-data`" you will notice if you monitor the requests that it gets POST'ed as "`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`" this is because it is done through ajax and ajax by itself can't process a file upload, you need to process them separately.

I have successfully implemented a "Insert Image" button which initialises the `Media Library` dialogue where you can browse your server for images and/or upload images.

Once the user clicks "Insert File" it inserts the full image url into a textbox in the widget so it's passed along like a normal field to your template.

This is how I achieved it:

In your widget.xml specify a new node:

```
<image translate="label">
    <label>Image</label>
    <visible>1</visible>
    <required>1</required>
    <type>label</type>
    <helper_block>
        <type>widgets/cms_wysiwyg_images_chooser</type>
        <data>
            <button translate="open">
                <open>Insert Image...</open>
            </button>
        </data>
    </helper_block>
</image>
```

The helper block type `<type>widgets/cms_wysiwyg_images_chooser</type>` is a custom class, so you can change it to anything you want as long as you create the class/files correctly.

```
<?php
class Stackoverflow_Widgets_Block_Cms_Wysiwyg_Images_Chooser extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
{
public function prepareElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
{
    $config = $this->getConfig();
    $chooseButton = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
        ->setType('button')
        ->setClass('scalable btn-chooser')
        ->setLabel($config['button']['open'])
        ->setOnclick('MediabrowserUtility.openDialog(\''.$this->getUrl('*/cms_wysiwyg_images/index', array('target_element_id' => $element->getName())).'\')')
        ->setDisabled($element->getReadonly());
    $text = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Text();
    $text->setForm($element->getForm())
        ->setId($element->getName())
        ->setName($element->getName())
        ->setClass('widget-option input-text');
    if ($element->getRequired()) {
        $text->addClass('required-entry');
    }
    if ($element->getValue()) {
        $text->setValue($element->getValue());
    }
    $element->setData('after_element_html', $text->getElementHtml().$chooseButton->toHtml());
    return $element;
}
}
?>
```

And that is it! You should now have a new field in your widget options called "Image" with a textbox and a button in which you can insert the url to an image on your server and display it from your template.

A quick explanation of how it works:

A button is created that has an `onclick` function that calls the `Media Library` dialogue by calling `MediabrowserUtility.openDialog()` which along is passed the parameter `target_element_id` which tells media library what element to set the value in once they user clicks "`Insert File`" so we simply pass along the `id` of our textbox in the widget for it to receive the url of the image that the user selected.

Hope this helps someone as I couldn't find any resources out there that explained how to do it so I spent quite a while digging through Magento to work it all out :)

What I would like to do in the future is have it so it displays the image after you select it in the widget, and it stores the url in a hidden field, but having an `onchange` bind is not fired when the value is set to the element from `js/mage/adminhtml/browser.js` in the `insert` function, so without changing the core files it is a lot harder to do. I thought about playing around with when the form gets focus again after the `Media Library` closes or a timer (pretty dodgey but would work), but I have other things to move on to and may come back to it later!

**UPDATE:**

The URL's that the `Media Library` generates are like so:

`http://www.yourwebsite.com/index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9Ind5c2l3eWcvd2lkZ2V0cy9iYW5uZXIvaG9tZXBhZ2UvZm9yZWdyb3VuZC9maXNoLXRhbmsucG5nIn19/key/e8167e3884e40b97d8985e7b84e7cbc7875f134e5f7e5946c9c2a482d0279762/`

Which are a cached image, and only work if the user is an admin. Stupid? Yes. If you insert the same image in to a CMS page when the html is generated for output it converts it to the original url on the server accessible via `/media/wysiwyg/path/to/file/photo.jpg`. We need the original url to show to the user, so what we can do is hook into the function that generates the widget html (when you click "Insert Widget") and look for `/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/` and replace it with the original URL to the image as the CMS page does.

In your `config.xml` for your custom widgets:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <widget>
            <rewrite>
                <widget>Stackoverflow_Widgets_Model_Widget</widget>
            </rewrite>
        </widget>
    </models>
</global>
```

Then create the model Widget `code\local\Stackoverflow\Widgets\Model\Widget.php`:

```
<?php
class Stackoverflow_Widgets_Model_Widget extends Mage_Widget_Model_Widget
{
    public function getWidgetDeclaration($type, $params = array(), $asIs = true)
    {
        foreach($params as $k => $v){
            if(strpos($v,'/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/') !== false){
                $parts = explode('/',parse_url($v, PHP_URL_PATH));
                $key = array_search('___directive', $parts);
                if($key !== false){
                    $directive = $parts[$key+1];
                    $src = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_filter')->filter(Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($directive));
                    if(!empty($src)){
                        $params[$k] = parse_url($src, PHP_URL_PATH);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return parent::getWidgetDeclaration($type, $params, $asIs);
    }
}
```

Which overrides the `getWidgetDeclaration` function which is called every time a the widget output is produced for a textarea/wysiwyg and looks through all the parameters and if it finds an image that is linked to the admin cache it will find out the original image and overwrite the variable in the array and call the original function with the parameters.

If the cached image is not found the function will work as normal.

**UPDATE: 13/09/2012**

As Jonathan Day pointed out you have to overwrite `Mage_Widget_Model_Widget_Instance` also if you want it to work in a Widget Instance.

I haven't had the need to add an image to a widget through a Widget Instance until now and was confused why my function didn't work, until I investigated and realised the "popup" widget instances use `Mage_Widget_Model_Widget` and the widget instances that are used on a Widget options tab (no popup) are `Mage_Widget_Model_Widget_Instance` and do not extend `Mage_Widget_Model_Widget` so do not inherit the functionality.

To add the functionality to `Mage_Widget_Model_Widget_Instance` simply add the line `<widget_instance>Petbarn_Widgets_Model_Widget_Instance</widget_instance>` to your `config.xml` so it will look like:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <widget>
            <rewrite>
                <widget>Stackoverflow_Widgets_Model_Widget</widget>
                <widget_instance>Stackoverflow_Widgets_Model_Widget_Instance</widget_instance>
            </rewrite>
        </widget>
    </models>
</global>
```

Then create the model Instance `code\local\Stackoverflow\Widgets\Model\Widget\Instance.php`:

```
<?php
class Petbarn_Widgets_Model_Widget_Instance extends Mage_Widget_Model_Widget_Instance
{
    protected function _beforeSave()
    {
        if (is_array($this->getData('widget_parameters'))) {
            $params = $this->getData('widget_parameters');
            foreach($params as $k => $v){
                if(strpos($v,'/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/') !== false){
                    $parts = explode('/',parse_url($v, PHP_URL_PATH));
                    $key = array_search('___directive', $parts);
                    if($key !== false){
                        $directive = $parts[$key+1];
                        $src = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_filter')->filter(Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($directive));
                        if(!empty($src)){
                            $params[$k] = parse_url($src, PHP_URL_PATH);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $this->setData('widget_parameters', $params);
        }
        return parent::_beforeSave();
    }
}
```

This time we are modifying the `widget_parameters` data at the start of the `_beforeSave()` function so it fixes up the url before it saves it.

You also have to ensure the `/js/mage/adminhtml/browser.js` javascript file is included (in my case it wasn't) to get the `MediabrowserUtility` functionality.

To ensure it is included, the easiest way is to include it for all of admin (didn't spend much time targeting it better).

Create a `local.xml` for adminhtml layouts (if you don't already have one): `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\local.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/browser.js</script></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

This will make Magento include `js/mage/adminhtml/browser.js` on every page of admin so `MediabrowserUtility` will always be available.

*NOTE: I'm using Magento Enterprise 1.11.2.0 so I'm not sure how it behaves on other versions.*

Comment: please note, that the final part of the answer also works for Widget Instances if you rewrite Mage_Widget_Model_Widget_Instance

Comment: there's a problem with that - magento produces following code: `{{widget type="various/lookbook_widget" lookbook_title="TEst" lookbook="category/8" image="{{media url="wysiwyg/Rio2016_logo.jpg"}}"}}` which gets screwed up by wysiwyg on the next save

Comment: @Netismine I'm not sure why that would happen, what version of Megento are you using? I'm using Enterprise 1.11.2.0. Based off what you are getting, it looks like `Mage::getModel('core/email_template_filter')->filter()` is returning the full block string and not just the URL. Have you tried logging what is returned at different points? A dirty hack would be to preg_match the url key to get the url or even just replace `str_replace(array('{{media url="','"}}'),'',$src);` the unwanted extra text.

Comment: CE 1.7 - 
Actually, on initial insert you get an admin image url, that saves fine and everything works. But when you try to resave, it breaks on frontend.
try pasting supplied code in a static block and try to pick up image attribute in your widget - you'll get broken parameter. Didn't dwelve into the logic, cause was under deadline, but it seems logical that magento can't parse `}}"}}`

Comment: I know this is very old, but could you give any pointers about the first part? Since I can't seem to get anything else as a label in the form.

I've got that XML between my parameters in the widget.xml and the file has the correct class and filename, I placed it in the Block folder since I assumed it should go there, I left the rest like you provided.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this use case by creating a custom field type for widgets:

```
<image>
    <label>Image</label>
    <description>Promotion image</description>
    <visible>1</visible>
    <type>widgetimagechooser/chooser</type>
</image>
```

I implemented a block `Aijko_WidgetImageChooser_Block_Chooser` that triggers the standard Magento image chooser element.

To solve the problem with the non clear url to the image file I implemented a custom controller `Aijko_WidgetImageChooser_Adminhtml_Cms_Wysiwyg_Images_ChooserController` that handles the return value from the Magento standard image chooser.

The value is added to a textbox in the widget. This relative url to the image then can be used to show the image in the frontend.

Feel free to try the extension available on [Github](https://github.com/aijko/aijko-widgetimagechooser) or install directly using [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/14537/).

Comment: Is this based on the answer by @Kus ?

Answer (score 2):

Thx krus for you answer! I've found a nicer way to solve the problem with the cached image URLs. I even had to do this, because your solution overwriting the Widget Model didn't work with Magento 1.7.0.2.

So what I have done is adding a new GET parameter `use_file_url` to the URL used for the Chooser Block:

```
$url    = $this->getUrl(
    '*/cms_wysiwyg_images/index',
    array(
        'target_element_id' => $element->getName(),
        'use_file_url' => 1
    )
);
```

This passes the GET parameter to the media browser. The next step is to pass this parameter to the `onInsertAction` of the `Mage_Adminhtml_Cms_Wysiwyg_ImagesController`. Do do this, you have to override the `getOnInsertUrl()` function of the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Wysiwyg_Images_Content` Block:

```
public function getOnInsertUrl()
{
    $useFileUrl = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('use_file_url', 0);
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/onInsert', array('use_file_url' => $useFileUrl));
}
```

Then you need to handle the new parameter in the `Mage_Adminhtml_Cms_Wysiwyg_ImagesController` controller:

```
public function onInsertAction()
{
    $useFileUrl = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('use_file_url', 0) == 1 ? true : false;
    $helper     = Mage::helper('cms/wysiwyg_images');
    $storeId    = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
    $filename   = $this->getRequest()->getParam('filename');
    $filename   = $helper->idDecode($filename);
    $asIs       = $this->getRequest()->getParam('as_is');

    Mage::helper('catalog')->setStoreId($storeId);
    $helper->setStoreId($storeId);

    if ($useFileUrl == false) {
        $image = $helper->getImageHtmlDeclaration($filename, $asIs);
    } else {
        $image = $helper->getImageMediaUrl($filename);
    }

    $this->getResponse()->setBody($image);
}
```

The last step is to override the `Mage_Cms_Helper_Wysiwyg_Images` helper and add the `getImageMediaUrl()` function:

```
public function getImageMediaUrl($filename)
{
    return $this->getCurrentUrl() . $filename;
}
```

I think this is a quite pretty approach, even though you have to ovverride 4 classes. But passing a GET parameter seems to be more future safe than parsing the cached URL.

Answer (score 0):

There is no file uploads for widgets. To solve that problem you may use magento media browser and select image like for wysiwyg editor, but there is other issue, media browser do not return clear url of image.

Answer (score 0):

Magento's Image custom attributes normally does not come to extension tab and you will have to go to Catalog>Product> Images to assign this attribute. But with some custom coding you can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As of Magento version 1.9.2.0 you will also need to add the following to your adminhtml layout file:

```
lib/flex.js
lib/FABridge.js
mage/adminhtml/flexuploader.js
```