# Images in Magento widgets continued

Tags: magento, widget, magento-1.7

I've been using Kus's answer found here:

[Images in Magento widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077755/images-in-magento-widgets/12470781)

However moving from my local to the testing server it looks like the class is not being read and I lose the button to upload.

This is my image block

```
 <widgetpress_list type="springwidget_press/List" module="springwidget_press">
   ....
  <image>
    <label>Press Image</label>
    <description>Image to be displayed on the page</description>
    <visible>1</visible>
    <type>label</type>
    <helper_block>
      <type>springwidget_press/imagechooser</type>
      <data>
        <button translate="open">
          <open>Insert Image...</open>
        </button>
      </data>
    </helper_block>
      </image>
    ....
   </widgetpress_list>
```

This is my class name in a file called app/code/local/Spring/Press/Block/ImageChooser.php

```
class Spring_Press_Block_ImageChooser extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
{
public function prepareElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
{

.
.
.
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a helper block but a custom field type.

Please have a look at my solution on [Github](https://github.com/aijko/aijko-widgetimagechooser). A sample implementation is available [here](https://github.com/aijko/aijko-widgetimagechooserexample).

An installation package is available on [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/14537/) as well.

Comment: That might be what is causing the issue, thanks for your reply! I will investigate and if it works, mark this correct.